# LINQ remove overlaps of datetime that are common in 2 lists

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have 2 lists of objects that both have a `Start` and `End` datetime.

```
public class TimePeriod {
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to add List A to List B. But there is case when the start and end data can overlap (non-inclusive so if `Start` of one object is the same as the `End` of another this won't be counted as an overlap. ) If they are overlap I want to not have to objects in my list.

I could do this with a few foreach loops but I feel that there is simpler/easier solution using linq.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong as this was not the most comprehensive. You want to essentially combine list A&B but not include duplicates of the same Start/End time?

Comment: @ChrisCruz No not just that also and span overlaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use LINQ, I'd say the Union() method with a custom equality comparer is the way to go:

```
public class TimePeriodEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<TimePeriod>
{
  public bool Equals(TimePeriod a, TimePeriod b)
  {
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (a.Start < b.Start && a.End > b.End) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((a.Start < b.Start && a.End > b.Start) || (a.Start < b.End && a.End > b.End)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(TimePeriod o)
  {
    // we have to force using the Equals method as it is only used to
    // break the tie when two objects have the same HashCode
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var xs = new[] {
    new TimePeriod() { Start = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1), End = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) },
    new TimePeriod() { Start = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1), End = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1) }
    new TimePeriod() { Start = new DateTime(2017, 10, 1), End = new DateTime(2018, 10, 1) }
};
var ys = new[] {
    new TimePeriod() { Start = new DateTime(2017, 10, 1), End = new DateTime(2017, 11, 1) },
    new TimePeriod() { Start = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1), End = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1) }
};  
var us = xs.Union(ys, new TimePeriodEqualityComparer());

foreach (var u in us) {
    Console.WriteLine(u);
}
```

Comment: Yes this would work but I am not looking just for the same start and end but also for overlaps. So where start is between another start en end or end is between another start andd end.